# Initial file list not showing actual files

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader, aws-php-sdk

I have implemented [initFiles](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/develop/features/session.html) to display already s3 uploaded files, but actual image thumbnails are not showing. Also, I can not click on the default thumbnail that is shown (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjyBm.jpg)). How can I see actual images and link works?

I have below JS snippet

```
session: {
        endpoint: "http://localhost/app/ci/php-s3-server/endpoint-cors.php?filelist"
    },
```

Response from endpoint-cors.php?filelist call is...

```
[{"name":"art_collage.png","uuid":"e3554aa0-c025-4653-bb71-4afe9d979f06","s3Key":"test\/e3554aa0-c025-4653-bb71-4afe9d979f06.png","s3Bucket":"kidkivetest"},{"name":"process_step_2.png","uuid":"e5d84dd7-458c-4601-9168-e16e747134d0","s3Key":"test\/e5d84dd7-458c-4601-9168-e16e747134d0.png","s3Bucket":"xx_my_bucket_xx"}]
```

S3 bucket structure has 2 images:

```
All Buckets /xx_my_bucket_xx/test
e3554aa0-c025-4653-bb71-4afe9d979f06.png
e5d84dd7-458c-4601-9168-e16e747134d0.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to display thumbnails in your [initial files list](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/session.html#server), you must provide a `thumbnailUrl` for each file in the list. For example:

```js
[{"name":"art_collage.png","uuid":"e3554aa0-c025-4653-bb71-4afe9d979f06","s3Key":"test\/e3554aa0-c025-4653-bb71-4afe9d979f06.png","s3Bucket":"kidkivetest", "thumbnailUrl": "http://mys3bucket.com/art_collage.png"}...]
```

Comment: I have added thumbnailUrl and now it shows diff default image http://imgur.com/qki15Gu than previous. But, actual image is not shown. Please see the response below.

Comment: [{"name":"art_collage.png","uuid":"e3554aa0-c025-4653-bb71-4afe9d979f06","s3Key":"test\/e3554aa0-c025-4653-bb71-4afe9d979f06.png","s3Bucket":"xx_my_bucket_xx","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/xx_my_bucket_xx\/test\/e3554aa0-c025-4653-bb71-4afe9d979f06.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJNRQDV3ZDPIU2ZEQ&Expires=1459473457&Signature=5bX5LFZrpC%2FjE%2FC5Bxh8i5x3Sp0%3D"},....}]

Comment: Most likely due to the fact that the image is coming from a domain that is different from the one hosting the page. This is a CORS issue, and is not resolvable in any version of IE (for images). S3 needs to return an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for the GET request in order for this to work in other browsers. A cross-browser solution is to proxy the thumbnail images though a server that you control on the same domain as the one hosting the page.

Comment: It worked after adding <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod> to CORSRule. Thanks Ray!

Comment: Be advised that I'm fairly certain that this won't work in any version of Internet Explorer. Cross-origin images are a bit special.

Comment: I was using chrome; based on your response I wanted to try on latest IE (windows 10 - Edge browser),and it worked there as well.

Comment: I still one pending question in this thread, when click on thumbnail it does not take me to image. Basically not clickable! Is there any trick here to be able to large image after the click?

Comment: Perhaps you can attach the large image URL to the clickable element using a `data-` attribute. When the user clicks the image, grab the URL from the `data-` attribute, create an `img` element using JavaScript, and then add the `img` to the DOM. Style to suit your needs. I did something similar in [my full-stack JavaScript image uploader blog post](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/11/01/full-stack-javascript-image-uploader-using-angularjs-node-js/), but that assumes you have access to the underlying file. Still, you can follow the logic/CSS for displaying a larger image in a modal.

Comment: After the upload if I click it will show the file; Would it be possible to have same behavior when I click on file that is from initFiles?

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible, but Fine Uploader doesn't provide such a feature. You can implement using the logic from my previous comment.

Comment: Sure and I will try. Reason for my ask is that, if link works...I was thinking of using lightbox javascript framework, which can show the image in the modal when clicked on image link (in my case all files are images).